# Is it possible to upload image or file to SkyDrive fom Metro Style App?

Tags: image, file, upload, microsoft-metro, onedrive

Is it possible to upload image or file to SkyDrive fom  Metro Style App? 
I have already found how to browse the file from SkyDrive. But I haven't found regarding uploading file to SkyDrive. If you reply me, it will be very thankful..

Comment: Are you using XAML or HTML5? If XAML, is it C# or C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileSavePicker to save files. This will of course give the user a chance to select where he wants to save to local documents folder or sky drive. The user is in control.

```
        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".YourExtension";
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "SampleFileName";
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices[".YourExtension"] = new List<string>() { ".YourExtension"};

        StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "A bunch of text to save to the file");
        }
```

Please note that in the sample code I am creating the content of the file in code. If you want the user to select an existing file from the computer then you will have to first use FileOpenPicker, get the file and then use FileSavePicker to save the contents of the selected file to the SkyDrive

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the file picker method works unless the user has the desktop app installed.

You should use a Sharing contract. If you add a data file (Storage Item) to share, then SkyDrive will be listed as a share target and the user gets a UI where they can choose where in their SkyDrive they want to save. This is how I implemented it in my app.

For more info...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771179.aspx

Comment: Thanks RobDurfee. It is very look like that it only supports for javascript and html5. I am developing for XAML/C#.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using XAML/JavaScript, the suggested solution is to use FilePicker.

The following link may help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150595.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mamta Dalal and Dangling Neuron, but there is problem. But it looks like I can't use FileSavePicker. I have to upload file(documnet, photo) not only text file. I have to copy from one path to another. If I use FileSavePicker, I have to write every file content (text, png, pdf, etc) and can't copy. Currently I am using FolderPicker. But unfortunately, FolderPicker doesn't support SkyDrive.My Code is As follow:

```
>FolderPicker saveFolder = new FolderPicker();
>saveFolder.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
>saveFolder.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;                
>saveFolder.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
>StorageFolder storagefolderSave = await saveFolder.PickSingleFolderAsync();
>StorageFile storagefileSave = [Selected storagefile with file picker];
>await storagefileSave.CopyAsync(storagefolderSave,storagefileSave.Name,NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

It will be greate that if FolderPicker supports SkyDrive or can copy file using FileSavePicker.

Comment: Hello everbody, I have found the ways that how to save any type of file(Document, photo). It works well even for SkyDrive. I will use FileSavePicker. Thank you for everything.